# Protection from Sim Card Cloning

Tags: android, simcard

My friend had a problem with her phone. Somehow it was acting weird, I knew someone was hacking her. I tried to help her by doing a PIN Lock and a factory reset of her android phone (version 6.0), but the day after, she received a SMS text message from her ISP saying that she was trying to access a feature that does not exist. How is it that the hacker is still able to get through her?

Comment: How I knew it was a hacker? unable to receive phone calls, sms text message slow, screen changing on its own, not being able to receive text message from some of her friends, sometimes receive a weird text WAP_push, etc

Comment: This doesn't necessarily mean that a hacker was involved . Anyway, you should add more details. Did the text message from the ISP mentioned a specific feature? Did the phone work regularly after the factory reset and before the text message? Did you try contacting technical support?

Comment: @A.Darwin the phone started functioning normal after factory reset and pin lock, but there was an SMS message telling her about the invalid features she entered, which she never did. Technical support was useless, they just play dumb

Comment: Try to get a replacement SIM card - tell them it's damaged. But I seriously doubt someone actually cloned the SIM.

Comment: @AndréBorie Are there other possibilities aside from cloning?

Comment: @Corbee outdated carrier infrastructure that breaks down and does funny things, and customer support are sadly monkeys who don't care so it's hard to get ahold of someone who can fix it.

Comment: @AndréBorie The reason that made me certain was the texting of WAP_PUSH that's usually means someone is trying unsuccessfully to send invisible SMS, there sometimes she get calls from someone without a number.

Comment: I second getting another SIM. If you did a factory reset, then the problem is likely somewhere else. Either the network is flaky or the SIM is compromised (can't reset that).

Answer (score 3):

The problem your friend experiences does not look like "SIM card cloning". Two signs which may indicate that someone has cloned your SIM card are the following:

- You see in your billing statement the calls/texts made from your phone which you did not make (however if you have a smartphone, this may also indicate that there is malware app running there, which generates those calls).
- When your friends call you, your phone doesn't ring although they hear the phone is ringing. And when they text you, you do not receive texts (but if you turn your phone into airline mode and turn it back, you will receive the text sent after that).

If your SIM is cloned, nothing you could do with your phone would help; resetting the phone is completely useless. You should go to your operator and get a new SIM.

Now, regarding your issues:

> How I knew it was a hacker? unable to receive phone calls,

May be a network problem. However if the calls get through and someone else picks up the phone, may be the result of SIM cloning (but make sure someone or something did not enable call forwarding service)

> sms text message slow,
>   screen changing on its own

This has nothing with SIM cloning.

> not being able to receive text message from some of her friends

If this means "I cannot receive texts from anyone from 2-3pm, even though I see in my billing the texts were received", this may be SIM cloning.

> sometimes receive a weird text WAP_push, etc

This looks more like malware or incompatibility between the handset and cell operator.